# How to dequeue a cell only once collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my Swift app I've the following collection view.
Every time that the user see the cell it reload data and every time it takes the image from database slowing the app.
How can I dequeue a cell only once?
Or how can I load the image only once?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


            selectedLocal = locals[indexPath.row - Int(indexPath.row / adsDensity)]

            let localCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            localCell.backgroundColor = currentTheme.backgroundColor

            localCell.layer.cornerRadius = localCell.frame.width / 32
            localCell.layer.shadowRadius = 5
            localCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
            localCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10)
            localCell.clipsToBounds = true

            localCell.coveImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            localCell.coveImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            localCell.coveImageView.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: “server_url”)

            localCell.titleLabel.text = selectedLocal.title
            localCell.placeLabel.text = selectedLocal.city
            localCell.timetableLabel.text = "Open"

            localCell.titleLabel.textColor = currentTheme.textColor
            localCell.placeLabel.textColor = currentTheme.textColor
            localCell.timetableLabel.textColor = currentTheme.textColor
            localCell.reviewLabel.textColor = currentTheme.textColor

            localCell.ratingView.backgroundColor = .clear
            localCell.ratingView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            localCell.ratingView.emptyImage =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "emptyStar")
            localCell.ratingView.fullImage =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "fullyStar")
            localCell.ratingView.rating = selectedLocal.rating

            return localCell

}
```

Comment: Since you already have a custom cell, put all the visual make ups to the cell itself.

Comment: I would suggest using https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher, it's a third party library which helps caching the images and this will prevent you from downloading images more than one time

Comment: `setImageFromURl()` being...? Do you manage a cache? `KingFisher`, `SDWebImage`, `AlamofireImage`, `AFNetworking` should be able to do so. Also as @Desdenova said, put that code into your custom cell file. Especially since you do a lot that is always the same, put it in `awakeFromNib()`, or `init(frame:style:)` (depending on how they are instanciate).

Comment: What are the disavadvantegs to put the code there?

Comment: @MarioJ When you dequeue a cell, you have it with all of it's visuals ready. But here, you are setting them over and again every time you need a cell. That could be your performance issue.

Comment: Thank you very much you were right!

Comment: But now how can I pass the value from collectionViewController to awakeFromNib in the cell?

Comment: Which value? You should leave data oriented stuff here as it is. Like `textLabel.text` and so.

Comment: I had to pass the selectedLocal object to awakefromnib in order to set the cell's contents.

Comment: No leave it here. And put everything about `currentTheme.textColor` in `willDisplayCell` to keep things tidy.